# Context Parameters value not string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, context-param

Let's say you write a Deployment Descriptor  with some context parameters and you want one of them to be an object,unfortunatelly I read that you cand only add string values to the  tag.

Is there a way to do this?I understood an example when it came to a database because you can put the look-up name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   ....>
 <context-param>
   <param-name>foo</param-name>
   <param-value>new foo()</param-value>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>BeerParamTests</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>TestInitParams</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>adminEmail</param-name>
   <param-value> likewecare@wikewdfs</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>BeerParamTests</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/Tester.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Provide some code so we can help you.

Comment: @tudoricc, which framework are you using ?

Comment: @Keval Trivedi I tried to summarize it the best I could

Comment: @Arvind I am not developing on a specific framework as I am trying to learn a bit of Java EE

Comment: @tudoricc, possibly you can go for reflection to build instance based on class qualified name given in the context-param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<context-param>
   <param-name>foo</param-name>
   <param-value>com.edu.Foo</param-value>
</context-param>`

In you java code, try the below

`Class.forName(getServletContext().getInitParameter("foo")).newInstance();`

but you will get only the empty object without any values assigned to the properties. will it work for you?

Comment: Yes it does,though I can not call a certain method from that class you can still do something with that class

Answer (score 1):

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>foo</param-name>
   <param-value>new foo()</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will just store `new foo()` as `String`.

`param-name` and `param-value` is based as key-value pair.

key to retrive the `String`  stored as value no use of this kind of value as it will only return `String`

```
String foo=getServletContext().getInitParameter("foo");//result : new foo()
```

> Let's say you write a Deployment Descriptor with some context
>   parameters and you want one of them to be an object

No. You can't store `Object` to the Deployment descriptor.Only `String` parameters are allowed.